# Javascript and jquery if function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Help me!
I have this kind of code but it never goes to IF function?
What is wrong?
jquery is working but does alert kill IF funtion?
IF funtion is working without jquery.

```
$.get("www.example.com", function(data) {
    var param = 'name'
    param = param.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + param + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(data);
    var paramValue = results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    alert(paramValue);
});

if (name == 'Bob') {
    window.location = ("www.example.com");
} else {
    window.location = ("www.example.com");
}
```

**UPDATE**

Hi here is the right code but I changed URL addresses. 
When I put `});` outside the *if/else* funtion it still doesn't work.

It will so "*ketju*" information right but it doesn't go any www.example after that.

So If/else is not working. I need this "ketju" information when user sign in to the website. I don't need to show this information just need to guide user to the right address. So this alert is not important.

Every user have interface information which contain lot of information about user.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get( "https://xxx.xx/learning/id2/bin/flash_api2?random=", 
function( data ) {
var param = 'ketju'
param = param.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + param + "=([^&#]*)"),
results = regex.exec(data);
var paramValue = results == null ? "" : 
decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
alert( paramValue );


if (ketju == 'Sweden') {    
window.location=("www.example.com");
 }else{
window.location=("www.example.com");
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where does your `name` should come from? You will get an `undefined` error ...

Comment: where is `name` variable defined?

Comment: please provide your html code so easy to trace your error

Comment: Do you have any errors triggered in your code before the if else? Keep in mind that the if/else block in your last example will execute before the get() callback, so the else should trigger. If it doesn't trigger, must be 'cause some error broke the js flow. Also, keep in mind you need to add 'http://' to the path in order to effectively go to the path.

Answer (score 0):

Alert doesn't "kill" if, don't worry about that. However note that your if/else is outside the function. So if you want it executed together with alert and the regex, put the `});` line after the if/else, not before it.

You are not defining a variable `name` and not assigning it the value `Bob` anywhere in your code (at least not it the shown code). You may want to change your if statement to

```
if (paramValue == 'Bob')
```

You will then get the parameter called 'name' from the regex, and the paramValue will give you the value of that parameter. So 'Alice', or 'Bob', or 'Hieronymous' or whatever.

(provided that there are no further problems with assigning the paramValue or with the regex)